# Glitchy looking desktop due to broken packages in 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, visual-artifacts

I tried updating my packages through Synaptic, and I haven't updated in a while so it took a while. As it was updating I got an error that I had broken packages and to fix it using `apt-get install -f`, seemingly because Synaptic became unresponsive/crashed during the update. I could not close synaptic, so I started troubleshooting and at some point clicked restart to see what kind of error I would get but it actually restarted, however xserver would not start so there was no desktop environment. I tried to run `apt-get install -f` again through tty2, but then it gave me some kind of error and told me to do the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. After that process, my desktop was usable and did not look buggy, but it didn't have my theme.

I ran `apt-get install -f` successfully this time around, and then finished the update, all in tty2 because I could not open a terminal window in my desktop. After the update finished I rebooted to my desktop looking like this. The login screen does not look like this, only the desktop environment looks like this, and this effect affects all applications in the desktop as well. Other than this the desktop environment is 100% usable. I also looked through .xsession-errors and the error seems to be documented here, but I don't know what to do with this info.

[image: How my desktop and all programs running inside it look]

```
Window manager warning: Log level 128: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Name com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar does not exist on the session bus
(process:4238): indicator-sound-WARNING **: 14:53:04.099: volume-control-pulse.vala:744: Unable to connect to dbus server at 'unix:path=/run/user/10>
(process:4238): indicator-sound-WARNING **: 14:53:04.119: media-player-list-mpris.vala:66: unable to find application 'vlc.desktop'
(caja:4195): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:53:04.782: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register cli>
** (process:4382): WARNING **: 14:53:05.057: could not find the desktop file for 'org.gnome.Calendar.desktop'
(process:4382): Indicator-Datetime-WARNING **: 14:53:05.127: Unrecognized TZID: 'Etc/Utc'
(process:4382): Indicator-Datetime-WARNING **: 14:53:05.148: Unrecognized TZID: 'Etc/Utc'
(process:4382): Indicator-Datetime-WARNING **: 14:53:05.270: Unrecognized TZID: 'Etc/Utc'  
(nm-applet:4289): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:53:05.434: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent  
(mate-settings-daemon:4164): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:53:05.937: Negative content width -2 (allocation 4, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node image>  
blueman-applet 14.53.06 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading DhcpClient because its conflict has higher priority  
blueman-applet 14.53.06 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading PPPSupport because its conflict has higher priority  
RuntimeError: object at 0x7ff91a7bc880 of type FolderColorMenu is not initialized    
RuntimeError: object at 0x7ff91aa079c0 of type RenameMenu is not initialized  
Window manager warning: Log level 128: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested) (child_setup specified)
(nm-applet:4289): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:53:09.424: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(nm-applet:4289): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:53:09.424: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(nm-applet:4289): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:53:09.429: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
(nm-applet:4289): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:53:09.434: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(nm-applet:4289): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:53:09.434: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(nm-applet:4289): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:53:09.440: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent  
INFO:root:The HUD is disabled via org.mate.hud in gsettings.
```

Comment: Have you tried a reboot

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, as the desktop isn't having problems displaying anything, it is just that there are some constant blocks of pixels and that the screen itself is warped. I also found errors in xsession-errors, which is not mentioned in that post

Comment: I suggest creating a temporary new account to see whether the issue indeed is system wide or due only to user configuration settings. I suggest this because you state the login screen displays properly. What desktop are you using and what version? Looks like Mate, but add that information to your post.